# NumPy ndarray broadcasting - shape (X,) vs (X, 1) to operate with (X,Y)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I have a NumPy `ndarray` which is shaped (32, 1024) and holds 32 signal measurements which I would like to combine into a single 1024 element long array, with a different weight for each of the 32. I was using `numpy.average` but my weights are complex and `average` performs a normalisation of the weights based on the sum which throws off my results.

Looking at the code for average I realised that I can accomplish the same thing by multiplying the weights by the signal array and then summing over the first axis. However when I try and multiply my (32,) weights array by the (32, 1024) signal array I get a dimension mismatch as the (32,) cannot be broadcast to (32, 1024). If I reshape the weights array to (32, 1) then everything works as expected, however this results in rather ugly code:

```
avg = (weights.reshape((32, 1)) * data).sum(axis=0)
```

Can anybody explain why NumPy will not allow my (32,) array to broadcast to (32, 1024) and/or suggest an alternative, neater way of performing the weighted average?

Comment: numpy can expand (32,) to `(1, 32)` to `(1024,32)`; but you have to give it permission to expand `(32,)` to `(32,1)`.  This avoids ambiguity in other circumstances, for example, when multiplying a (32,) by a (1024,).  More on this in my recent answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39238203/901925

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Generic setup for alignment between `(X,)` and `(X,Y)` shaped arrays**

On the question of why `(32,)` can't broadcast to `(32, 1024)`, it's because the shapes aren't aligned properly. To put it into a schematic, we have :

```
weights :         32
data    :  32 x 1024
```

We need to align the only axis, which is the first axis of `weights` aligned to the first axis of `data`. So, as you discovered one way is to `reshape` to `2D`, such that we would end up with a singleton dimension as the second axis. This could be achieved by introducing a new axis with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) : `weights[:,np.newaxis]` or `weights[:,None]` or a simple reshape : `weights.reshape(-1,1)`. Hence, going back to the schematic, with the modified version we would have :

```
weights[:,None] :  32 x    1
data            :  32 x 1024
```

Now, that the shapes are aligned, we can perform any generic element-wise operation between these two with the result schematic looking like so -

```
weights[:,None] :  32 x    1
data            :  32 x 1024
result          :  32 x 1024
```

This would broadcast `weights` and the relevant element-wise operation would be performed with `data` resulting in `result`.

**Solving our specific case and alternatives**

Following the discussion in previous section, to solve our case of element-wise multiplication, it would be `weights[:,None]*data` and then sum along `axis=0`, i.e. -

```
(weights[:,None]*data).sum(axis=0)
```

Let's look for neat alternatives!

One neat and probably intuitive way would be with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('i,ij->j',weights,data)
```

Another way would be with matrix-multiplication using [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), as we lose the first axis of `weights` against the first axis of `data`, like so -

```
weights.dot(data)
```

Comment: Clear and thorough answer, thanks. I didn't know about `np.einsum` - while it is admittedly a neat approach I don't think it is obvious to people who aren't familiar with the grammar. The `np.dot` style comes closer to something which "just makes sense" and is nicely compact.